# Wrap model with sklearn interface

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, wrapper, gridsearchcv

what is the best way to wrap an existing model with sklearn `BaseEstimator` interface to be gridsearchCV compatible? The model that I have hasn't neither set_param nor get_params. My approach is the following:

```py
class Wrapper(BaseEstimator):
    
    def __init__(param1, param2):
        self.model = ModelClass(param1, param2)
    
    def fit(data):
        self.model.fit(data)
        return self

    def predict(data):
        return self.model.predict(data)

    def get_params(self, deep=True): # ?
        return self.model.__dict__

    def set_params(self, **parameters): # ?, have I to recreate model?
        for parameter, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self.model, parameter, value)
        return self
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `get_params` method, you can return a dictionary of the parameters of the Wrapper instance using the `__dict__` attribute. This will allow `GridSearchCV` to access the parameters of the Wrapper instance and use them for hyperparameter tuning.

Don't forget to add `self.param1 = param1` and `self.param2 = param2` under `__init__` to allow access for get and set.

```
class Wrapper(BaseEstimator):
    
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.model = ModelClass(param1, param2)
    
    def fit(self, data):
        self.model.fit(data)
        return self

    def predict(self, data):
        return self.model.predict(data)
    
    def score(self, data):
        return self.model.score(data)

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {'param1': self.param1, 'param2': self.param2}

    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        self.param1 = parameters.get('param1', self.param1)
        self.param2 = parameters.get('param2', self.param2)
        self.model = ModelClass(self.param1, self.param2)
        return self
```

Example of using `GridsearchCV`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {'param1': [1, 10, 100], 'param2': [0.01, 0.1, 1]}

model = Wrapper()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
test_score = grid_search.score(X_test, y_test)
print(f'Test score: {test_score:.2f}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't understand why save `ModelClass` params in the wrapper `__init__`. If I change those parameters the corresponding parameters in the model don't change, isn't it? And if I want to get the parameters I can access it through `self.model.__dict__[value]`. Sorry for my ignorance :) .

Comment: @Gardo, If you update the `param1` and `param2` instance variables of the Wrapper class, the corresponding parameters in the `ModelClass` instance will not automatically be updated because they are separated. If you would like to modify them, you require to use `set_params()`. Also, `self.model.__dict__[value]` is not recommended, it is bypassed.